# Can't Browse to Server on LAN

Tags: apache-2.4, local-area-network

I have a very simple LAN setup and am trying to connect to an Apache server running on the LAN. The server IP is 192.168.1.178. I'm trying to connect from a box on same LAN with IP of 192.168.1.161. Attempting to connect from browser results in error saying site is unreachable. I can ping the server and SSH into the server. But, telnet and curl result in no route to host errors.

Both boxes are set up with static IPs. DNS for static connection is 192.168.1.1. Both boxes are running Manjaro and no firewalls are turned on. Apache access logs show no attempt to connect and there are no errors in the Apache error logs.

I don't think it's an Apache problem, but I've included results from 'apachectl -S' just in case. Thanks in advance.

```
apachectl -S
[/home/tim]
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/srv/http"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="http" id=33 not_used
Group: name="http" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with your computer's network configuration or with the network itself, not Apache. Home computing and networking questions are not on topic here though.

Comment: Just to close the loop. I discovered that a firewall was running, which was causing the problem.